# How can I drag virtual files from java swing to windows desktop?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to drag a "virtual" file from Java swing application and drop it onto windows desktop?
By "virtual" I mean "not local" file that needs to be downloaded/prepared which could potentially take a long time. I have a client-server application that shows a view of remote files. When user drops that file on desktop, I would like to receive a notification of the destination folder which I would use to start the download process with the Java application.

Please offer any help or guidance as I've been looking for a solution for a while now.

Comment: [Drag And Drop between JList and Windows Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/591/Drag-And-Drop-between-JList-and-Windows-Explorer) should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I analyzed that example and it is quite irrelevant. It handles dragging of local files which already exist on the local system. I need to be notified about the drop destination so I can "generate" the file asked for and put to the destination folder via Java application acting as a download manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar myself, and I have some unfortunate news for you: Windows cannot handle promised files, nor does it inform your java application as to where the files are dropped. Simply put, there is no way to handle remote drag-and-drop via the DnD api only.

You need to create empty files in some temp directory somewhere, and hand windows those files when the mouse leaves the swing window. You also need to set up a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) on the local filesystem to receive notification of file creation. After DropEnd, you check for empty files of the correct name but not in your temp directory, and effect the transfer at that point (move the remote files into the empty files that were dropped).